# Поиск слов в текстовом файле с помощью Java

Tags: java, txt

Как в java найти несколько слов из txt документа и вывести их в консоль?
Прежде считывал одно слово так:

```
public class FraziologizmLoad {
    private static final String PATH = "./lib/fralogizm.txt";
    public String line;
    public String getStr;
    public void adf(String text) throws IOException {
        String searchWord = "Биться"; 
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File(PATH)); 
        byte[] content = new byte[fis.available()];
        fis.read(content);
        fis.close();
        String[] lines = new String(content, "Cp1251").split("\n"); 
        int i = 1;
        for (String line : lines) {
            String[] words = line.split(" ");
            for (String word : words) {
                if (word.equalsIgnoreCase(searchWord)) {
                    FileInputStream fs= new FileInputStream(PATH);
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fs));
                    for(int i2 = 0; i2 < i-1; ++i2)
                    br.readLine();
                    String str = new String (br.readLine());    
                    aa(str);
                    System.out.println(str);
                }
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
```

часть txt файла:

Игра (не) стоит свеч — выгода от предприятия (не) превышает затраты на него же.

Игра в одни ворота — ситуация, в которой одна сторона получает все плюсы, вторая же несет все проблемы.

Играть в бирюльки — заниматься малозначимым делом.

Играть в кошки-мышки — соревноваться с заведомо неравными партнерами.

Comment: В чем смысл приведенного кода?  Зачем каждый раз в самом глубоко вложенном цикле перечитывается информация из файла?  Какой результат ожидается для заданного входного файла?  Должны ли выводиться строки, содержащие _одно_, _несколько_ или _все_ входные слова?

Comment: Код написал на всякий случай, вдруг можно было что-то изменить для результата. Нужно что бы выводились строки, содержащие несколько входных слов, а если можно то и для одного тоже

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примерный вариант для случая, когда нужно совпадение всех слов:

```
List<String> searchWords = new ArrayList<>();
searchWords.add("Биться");
searchWords.add("головой");
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File(PATH));
byte[] content = new byte[fis.available()];
fis.read(content);
fis.close();
String[] lines = new String(content, "Cp1251").split("\n");
for (String line : lines) {
  String[] words = line.split(" ");
  if (searchWords.stream().allMatch(sW -> Arrays.stream(words).anyMatch(w -> w.equalsIgnoreCase(sW)))) {
    aa(str);
    System.out.println(line);
  }
}
```

Не понятно что тут за метод "aa", но оставил его...

Если достаточно совпадения одного из слов, то allMatch можно заменить на anyMatch

Comment: Ещё можно добавить toLower(), если регистр не важен

Comment: Mr.AntonDer,  equalsIgnoreCase используется, он уже игнорирует регистр